# How to clone between Old Repository Develop Branch and New Repository Develop branch using commit ID in GitHub?

Tags: github

I have two branches (old and new) from two different repositories (old and new) that I want to clone using a commit ID, I followed the below steps, but it is cloning the whole repository, instead I want it to clone from a Develop branch in old repository to a Develop branch in new repository.

```
git clone --mirror <old repo>
cd <old repo name>
git remote add new-origin <new repo>
git push new-origin --mirror
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/git-clone-branch-how-to-clone-a-specific-branch/

**Option 1:**

`git clone --branch <branchname> <remote-repo-url>`

**Option 2:**

`git clone --branch <branchname> --single-branch <remote-repo-url>`